# In lambda calculus, how many fixed-point combinators are there?

Tags: lambda-calculus, fixed-points

In lambda calculus, how many fixed-point combinators are there?

I am familiar with Curry’s paradoxical combinator a.k.a. the $Y$-combinator and Turing’s fixed-point combinator, $\Theta$, which are both fixed-point combinators and I am aware there are others.

- Is there a tally of how many fixed-point combinators there are?
- Do we know if all have been found?
- Are there infinitely many? Do we know of a way to generate arbitrary many different fixed-point combinators?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nLab [article on fixed-point combinators](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/fixed-point+combinator#unityped_calculus) mentions this:

> Another construction is due to (Klop 07):
> $$Y_K = LLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLL$$
> where
> $$L = \lambda abcdefghijklmnopqstuvwxyzr. r (thisisafixedpointcombinator)$$
>
> Note that $Y_K$ is $L$ repeated 26 times, and the string
> $thisisafixedpointcombinator$ contains 27 characters.

This seems to suggest a way to generate fixed-point combinators. The linked paper (Klop07) also mentions this:

> how to derive new fixed point combinators from given ones

@mohottnad brought to my attention the following excerpt from the Wikipedia [article on Fixed-point combinator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_combinator#cite_ref-bimbo_8-0):

> In untyped lambda calculus fixed-point combinators are not especially rare. In fact there are infinitely many of them. (Bimbó 11)

### References

- Jan Willem Klop, *[New Fixed Point Combinators from Old](http://www.cs.ru.nl/barendregt60/essays/klop/)*, in
  *Reflections on Type Theory, Lambda Calculus, and the Mind: Essays Dedicated to Henk Barendregt on the Occasion of his 60th Birthday*
- Bimbó, Katalin (27 July 2011). Combinatory Logic: Pure, Applied and Typed. p. 48. ISBN 9781439800010.

Answer (score 1):

From your third point, I assume that you ask this question not up to $\beta$-equivalence?
In that case, there are infinitely many, because of the identity combinator $1 = \lambda x. x$.

For example: define $v = \lambda xy. (1y)(xxy)$. Then $vv$ is a fixed point combinator. (Note the similarity with $\Theta$.)

I cannot say anything about the case where we identify $\beta$-equivalent terms, however.

Comment: I guess excluding $\alpha$-equivalence. So $(\lambda f.(\lambda x.f(xx))(\lambda x.f(xx)))$ and $(\lambda g.(\lambda y.g(yy))(\lambda y.g(yy)))$ would be considered the same.

Comment: OK, then you can use what I wrote above to make infinitely many fixed point combinators. (Note that putting identities _around_ the combinator would not work, they need to be inside somehow so that they are propagated.)